# Calling Static method Main using name of a class in which it is used - C# program

Tags: c#, .net, program-entry-point

I have read at least one class should contain Main method since the entry point of execution is the Main(). Lets see the code below.

```
using System;
namespace consoleApplication
{
    class sample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Demo program");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

We know that a static method inside a class can be invoked using dot operator with the class name. So can we call Main() as

```
sample.Main();
```

just like we call

```
Console.WriteLine();
```

and kindly tell me whether it is syntactically right or not even if we are not using the same.

Comment: Are you asking why you don't have to call `Main` in your code? If so, it's because the OS is doing it for you.

Comment: How is it not done like that?

Comment: How would you propose to call the code which then calls `sample.Main`?

Comment: Are you asking if you could call sample.Main() from another project? As if it were a library you were referencing? Main() is just the entry point for console applications.

Comment: jsmith: Exactly. Can we call it from another project?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @rajesh Are you trying to load/run the compiled .exe or simply wish to load a DLL into memory to run code of?

Comment: You must add an assembly in Project settings - References, and then use your Main() as consoleApplication.sample.Main();

Comment: If you want to write `sample.Main()` you need to write `using consoleApplication;` in head of your source-file

Comment: Is that an answer to your question? Or you want to call entry-point dynamically, like file loader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the class and `Main()` method are created as private members. If you absolutely wanted to, you could make them public members then call them from another project.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class sample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("My Output...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            sample.Main();
        }
    }
}
```

> Output: "My Output..."

However, I do not know why this would be necessary. This is what libraries are created for. I would instead create a class library and make my static class/methods within it.

Your `Main()` method is simply the entry point for your console application. Every application has an entry point. I cannot think of a use case in which you would create several application projects, then call the `Main()` methods from other projects. I would instead, make a new project that will be used as a library, not an application. This is what a class library is meant for.

The answer to the last question, is this syntactically correct? Yes. Again, I stress that this is not good practice. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx) "Main must be static and it should not be public." Just because it can be done, does not mean that it should be.

Comment: @asawyer Not for the two I just created in Visual Studio 2010... static void Main(string[] args)

Comment: I retract my statement. I must have edited it ages ago for some reason and forgot. Sorry! :)

Comment: Not sure why I got the downvote.. This absolutely works, I didn't say it was a good idea. But you CAN do it... Please give reason for downvote.

Comment: see guys, I just want to know whether it could be done or not and it doesn't mean that I am trying to achieve certain functionality using this.